# Data payloads in requests module?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests

This is a site-specific issue that I'm curious about—as I'm still learning much of the dynamics of web-requests.

I know how to add a data payload to a http request using the request library for Pyhton as such:

```
payload = {
    "data": "whatever_data_string_here"
}

r = requests.get('url', data=payload)
```

What I still largely have little clue regarding is when and how to apply this type of approach. I was playing around with different site types trying to find unique ways to understand different approaches in requesting data, and have become stumped on the following site:

```
aaimedicine(dot)com/fap/
```

Ignoring their poor choice in abbreviation, I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through requests for the different specialty types in their form.

The general functionality of the site is that you can select an option from the `Specialty` dropdown form, click `Search`, and be shown relevant results.

To the best of my ability, it seems that data is retrieved through a data submitted with the request header, that looks like the following:

`specialty=Massage_Bodywork&specother=&state=ALL&Submit=Search+%C2%BB`

I've found that by inspecting the request headers in the console view, but don't exactly know how to apply that to my http request.

I've tried the following:

```
for option in options:
    r = requests.get('http://www.aaimedicine(dot)com/fap/', data={"Form Data": "specialty={}&specother=&state=ALL&Submit=Search+%C2%BB".format(option)})
```

This doesn't respond with the data I'm looking for, and just gives the html of the original url without before a choice was submitted.

I'd like to know how to make these types of requests so that iterating over the options would be possible.

Comment: You can not use `requests` in your case. that website does not have an `API`.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: @ boardrider perhaps you'd like to suggest which particular section you feel I failed to soak in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realized that this type of `POST` request can be made in this instance by taking the following header source:

`specialty=Speciality_Choice_Value&specother=&state=ALL&Submit=Search+%C2%BB`

And utilizing it through the request module as such:

```
payload = {
        "specialty": "Speciality_Choice_Value",
        "specother": "",
        "state": "ALL",
        "Submit": "Search+%C2%BB",
    }

r = request.post('theurl.com', data=payload)
```

Comment: Please review my answer below, and upvote or mark as as accepted if it helped you in thinking through the problem.

Comment: this answer should be at top

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the html source of the `/fap` page, you will see

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

So I am guessing you may just need to use requests.post() instead of .get().

But as ettanany mentioned in the comment above, this is really not a good idea because it's not a web api (it is subject to change at anytime, and break your script).

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning a lot of the fundamentals of web requests. This isn't for any long term use; more of just a learning exercise for me to gain a deeper understanding. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: Sounds good- do not forget to upvote or accept my answer, that is the best way to say thanks on 'SO'. :)

Comment: Your answer certainly contributed to my discovery of the method in which I was able to make this request, which I've included as an answer below. Ultimately, I was improperly formatting the `data=` argument used to specify data to the request.

Comment: And you changed .get() to .post() :)